# Arduino OOP and [this] keyword

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, library, sketch, safety

Lets say I have a sketch called **mysketch.ino** with these contents:

```
String globalString = "ThisisGlobal";
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

How can I pass **THIS** sketch `mysketch.ino` as an object or its reference to a `.h` file named
`StringChanger.h` with the following contents, so that `StringChanger.h` can change somevariables belonging to `mysketch.ino`.

```
class StringChanger{
   template <typename T> // or type of mySketch.ino i don't know what i'm doing 
   void changeString(T t) {  //a Reference Or Object Or Whatever
      t.globalString = "GotYouAndChangedYou";
   }
}
```

I wan't to have simple usage in the `mySketch.ino`.
For instance:

```
#include "StringChanger.h"

StringChanger change(**this**);  // perhaps default empty constructor here

String globalString = "ThisisGlobal";

void setup(){
    change.changeString(); // perhaps pass reference to **this** here
}
void loop(){}
```

How can I accomplish this (give a class an object so that it can change some value of that object) in general and not neccesarily in this context.
Errors I currently get:

```
invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
invalid use of 'this' at top level.
```

Comment: `Arduino OOP and [this] keyword` - it's C++. So whatever works in C++ works in Arduino.

Comment: `StringChanger change(**this**);` this doesn't make any sense at all, sorry.

Comment: I thought stack over flow would bold the string sorry. I meant change(this); and I understand Arduino has less of c++ especially the heavy complex parts because of the speed of micro controllers . I don't think if it works in C++ it's works in Arduino

Comment: It's nothing to do with speed. Exceptions are disabled by a command-line option. The rest is just pure C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sketch isn't an object. It is merely a collection of variables, functions and, of course, classes.

Your example seems to be trying to make things incredibly complex when they don't need to be.

There are a number of ways of referencing things in one file from another - whether or not they are in a class.  The simplest is to use the `extern` keyword.  This is used in a file where you want to reference a variable or function that is defined in the global scope of another file. It says "This variable is global, but it's defined somewhere else."

```
// Sketch
String myString = "foo";

// Library
extern String myString;
// ... later on ...
myString = "bar";
```

Of course, that means that the name of the variable is fixed and cannot change.  So you can pass the variable to whatever it is you want to use that variable in.  That could be as simple as passing it to your "changer" function:

```
// Sketch
String myString = "foo";
StringChanger change;
// ... later ...
change.changeString(myString);

// Library
class StringChanger {
    public:
        void changeString(String &stringToChange) {
            stringToChange = "bar";
        }
};
```

If you want to "tie" the variable to the class so you don't have to pass it each time you could pass it to the constructor and have the class remember it:

```
// Sketch
String myString = "foo";
StringChanger change(myString);
// ... later ...
change.changeString();

// Library
class StringChanger {
    private:
        String *_string;
    public:
        StringChanger(String &string) {
            _string = &string;
        }
        void changeString() {
            *_string = "bar";
        }
}
```

And there's a myriad of other ways of doing it.

Comment: First part of your answer is what I want to do because I simply want that calling the constructor changes the string that is finds that extern string named myString and changes it to another. I don't want to use the function that accepts a string reference. Thanks @Majenko

Comment: Why not just make a function that changes an external string? I don't see why you would make a class just to change some external thing, which is not in the class, and doesn't do anything else.

Comment: @NickGammon Maybe that's just an example and he's really doing something completely different. Who knows with these kids? Either way, what he is doing is most likely not the right way of doing things and using getters and setters is more likely the right solution for managing his class.

Comment: Sounds like one of the better examples of [the X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) that I have seen in a while.

Comment: @NickGammon Quite probably. I have pretty much given up trying to convince people that they are asking the wrong question though.

Comment: Yes, we need a close reason: "this is the wrong question". :)

Comment: @NickGammon I'm guilty of falling into x-y situations all the time. Not always but specifically when i write the type of usage i want then try to solve the problem. Speaking of which checkout my other [problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561496/generating-executable-code-dynamically) please.